# Recursive Function Continuing After Return

Tags: c++, recursion

EDIT: The issue below was solved.  But, I had a follow up question. Sometimes my professor doesn't return when making a recursive call. How do I know when I should return a recursive call vs when I should just call the function recursively?

I am writing a recursive function to see if a binary search tree contains a certain key.  The phrase "Key Match Contains" prints, so the key is found, but the function still returns false.  I noticed it returns false whenever the left subtrees are searched.  Any ideas on what is going wrong?  Thank you in advance.

Internal Method:

```
template <typename K>
bool Multiset<K>::Contains(std::unique_ptr<Node> &n, const K &key) {
  if (!n) {
    std::cout << "Contains returns null" << std::endl;
    return false;
  }

  if (n->key == key) {
    std::cout << "Key match Contains" << std::endl;
    return true;
  } else if (key < n->key) {
    Contains(n->left, key);
  }
  return Contains(n->right, key);
}
```

External Method:

```
template <typename K>
bool Multiset<K>::Contains(const K &key) {
  return Contains(root, key);
}
```

Comment: in your `else if`, you're missing a `return` before the recursive call.

Comment: That fixed it, thank you!

Comment: I had a follow up question.  Sometimes my professor doesn't return when making a recursive call.  How do I know when I should return a recursive call vs when I should just call the function recursively?

Comment: If the function takes in parameters by reference, or can change global state, then you might not need to return from it. Otherwise, the only useful thing to do is return the result of the recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

You are dropping the search result in the part:

```
    Contains(n->left, key);
```

It should be, for example, like this:

```
    if (Contains(n->left, key)) return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `return Contains(n->left, key);` not just `Contains(n->left, key);`